# How can I prepare a reactive dataset for reuse in downstream chunks in a shiny Rmd?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

In the example below I have set up a `selectizeInput()` element which I would like to use to alter `my_data` and return an object that can be used in additional chunks of the Rmd file.

````r
---
title: "A shiny Report"
runtime: shiny
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: false
    fig_caption: true
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# data
my_data <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(name = rownames(mtcars))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
selectizeInput("carsID",
               "Cars:",
               selected = "Honda Civic",
               multiple = TRUE,
               choices = my_data$name)
```

### Show selection
```{r, results="asis"}
renderUI(paste0(input$carsID, collapse = ", "))
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filtering needs to happen within a `reactive` consumer while the return value of this consumer can be written to a variable. Downstream use of this variable is then enabled by addressing it via its name and `()`.

````r
---
title: "A shiny Report"
runtime: shiny
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: false
    fig_caption: true
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

# data
my_data <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(name = rownames(mtcars))
```

```{r, results="asis"}
selectizeInput("carsID",
               "Cars:",
               selected = "Honda Civic",
               multiple = TRUE,
               choices = my_data$name)
```

### Show selection
```{r, results="asis"}
renderUI(paste0(input$carsID, collapse = ", "))
```

```{r}
my_data_filt <- reactive({
  my_data %>%
    filter(name %in% input$carsID)
})
```

### Dynamic table
```{r, results="asis"}
renderTable(my_data_filt())
```
````